# How to delete all Facebook Graph API apprequests?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
$request_url ="https://graph.facebook.com/".$uid."/apprequests?".$access_token;
$requests = file_get_contents($request_url);
```

This gets all the requests for a user. But how do I delete all of them at once? Facebook only has an example for deleting them one by one.

Thanks!

Comment: Loop through the set and apply the delete on each one?

Comment: Did you even read what I wrote?

Answer (score 4):

You can't delete multiple items in a single operation (like you can with, say, SQL). You will need to iterate to some degree to specify the unique URL for each request. What you *can* do is batch up your operations into a single request to Graph API.

More info [here at FB](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/batch/).

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but I found it searching on Google so I thought anyone could need an answer now.

The best method for me, is to send all the request ids to Facebook on a single api call.

Your request ids must be on the format requestid_userid, like 12345_67890, supposing you have all the IDs inside an array ($array_of_request_ids), the code (PHP) would be like this:

```
$ids = implode(',', $array_of_request_ids);
$facebook->api("/?ids={$ids}", 'DELETE');
```

That should delete all the requests.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if($requests) {
    foreach($requests as $key => $data) {

        $request_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" .
                       $data['id'] . "?" . $access_token;

        $requests = file_get_contents($request_url);

        //Delete a request.  
        $delete_url = $request_url . "&method=delete";
        $result = file_get_contents($delete_url);

    }
  }
```